# PHP: How do you create table with active record?

Tags: php, mysql, create-table, phpactiverecord

Believe it or not I can not find an answer anywhere, it must be very simple...

I installed composer and imported in my project active record in my Test App.

Now i am trying to create a table dynamically from my script, something like

- The user register
- username and password get stored into user table
- a new table for this user needs to be created

with plain php i would send a raw query(`CREATE TABLE 'john_doe'...`) with PDO

Is there a way to do it with Active Record?

---

Thanks, I tried using a model for an already existing table to create new tables and it worked, not sure yet about create a Connection object.

The documentation of this active record is not really for beginners, i am to use to the example of php.net, wish all the documentation were like that.

Comment: Please explicitly state which package you mean by "Active Record"

Comment: i am using php-activerecord/php-activerecord from www.phpactiverecord.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a raw query using [phpactiverecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) using the [`Connection::query('CREATE TABLE 'john doe'...)`](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Connection#methodquery) method.

If you using activerecord in your models, you can use the [`Model::query('blah');`](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Model#methodquery) method.

Comment: Class 'Connection' not found in C:\wamp\www\bl\login\register_controller.php. Do i need to prefix with namespace?

Comment: I have no idea what your controller is doing.. Use your connection resource, for example: `$db->query('blah');` or maybe `MyAwesomeConnection::query('blah');`

Comment: @frapet Use your connection

Comment: I am sorry it seems i missed something all i have is a file with `ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg){bla bla`  and the models for my tables, i am looking at the documentation but don tsee anywhere how to specify a connection object, feel so dumb now

Comment: But every model belongs to a table so i can not use(in theory) a model for a table that already exists for create a new one, maybe i need to create dynamically a new model and use it for create a new table...not sure how to create a model dynamically, i'll check the documentation

Comment: Somewhere you must be creating a connection. Use that to run your queries.